# How can I get the Binary Cross Entropy from the Cross Entropy function for GANs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, loss-functions, cross-entropy

I got the definition of log-likelihood by Goodfellow's Deep Learning book:
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:loglikelihood}
    \theta_{ML} = {argmax}\sum_{i=1}^{m} \log p_{model}(x_i; \theta).
\end{equation}
I saw the definition of empirical distribution in the same book and is something like this:
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:empiricaldistribution} 
    \hat{p}_{data}(x) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \delta(x - x_{i})
\end{equation}

Where Dirac delta is $\delta(x - x_{i})=1$ when $x_{i}=x$ and 0 when they are different.

From the definition of expected value with respect to a function f(x) I could derive the log-likelihood as an expectation with respect to the empirical distribution by dividing the log-likelihood equation by m:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:expectedloglikelihood1}
     \frac{1}{m}\theta_{ML} = {argmax} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{m}  \log p_{model}(x_i; \theta)
\end{equation}

And by minimizing the equation I could derive the cross-entropy H function:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:expectedvalue)} 
    {argmin} (-1) \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}} (\log p_{model}(x_i; \theta)) = H(\hat{p}_{data},p_{model})
\end{equation}

As I've read more about here I've found an answer relating this proof with Monte-Carlo, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427686/maximum-likelihood-estimation-and-expected-value) and reproduce the part that intrigues me:

> Again, we don't the true probability distribution $p_{data}(x)$, but we have samples. By Monte-Carlo method, we have
> $$\sum p_{data(x)}\log p_{model}(x;\theta) \approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\log p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta)$$

So how Monte-Carlo method works under these circunstances? To get the binary cross-entropy in the next step of the proof do I need to change the definition of Dirac delta?

Comment: I’m fairly sure that you’re mixing up continuous and categorical distributions by giving equations without context. Of course, I can’t check this because I don’t have the context.

Comment: Well, i'm using log-likelihood to do an inference to a distribution to a discriminative and a generative model which their loss-functions are special cases of binary cross entropy which comes from cross-entropy equation (i think...). I think my confunsion is related to many concepts I'm learning quite now.